# Unable to submit a Modal form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal form to add a record. However, clicking the submit button does absolutely nothing. This is a partial view and it loads very well on clicking the 'Add' button on the parent view. However, the form on the partial view does not submit. I have reviewed some of the related posts. However I have had no resolution so far. Here is the code -

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Cases.CaseViewModels.AddDiseasePhotosViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-dialog">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDiseasePhoto", "Cases", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmModal", @name = "frmModal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <i class="fa fa-laptop modal-icon"></i>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Disease Photo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @TempData["SuccessMsg"]

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class="form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload File</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PicFileUpload, new { type = "file", id = "file1" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PicFileUpload, string.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="AjaxPost" class="btn btn-primary">Add Photo</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#frmModal');
        //Submit button
        var submitButton = $("#AjaxPost");
        var infoForm = $("#frmModal");
        submitButton.click(function () {
            SubmitInfo(infoForm);
        });
    });

    function SubmitInfo(formContainer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("AddDiseasePhoto", "Cases")",
            type: 'post',
            data: formContainer.serialize()         
        });
    }        
</script>
```

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: @Erik Thanks a lot for your reply. In my case, the modal form was nested in the form from the parent view. I have gotten the modal to work correctly after isolating the form from the parent view. Thank you so much. Can you post this as an answer so that I can select it? On a different note, you've mentioned about the duplication of included scripts. Does the modal need any specific js files included despite having it included in the parent view? I did have js files included in the modal view and found that including them or removing them did not make any difference. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to look at the web page as a whole once it's assembled.  The Layout, The page, the partial pages, all together.  So, if a partial includes a script that is already included in the parent, that can cause issues.  However, if it's included in the parent then you don't need to include it in the partial.

Answer (score 1):

Your "submit" button is typed as "button", not "submit". A button of type "button" does nothing on it's own, and will not submit your form. Change it to:

```
<button type="submit" id="AjaxPost" class="btn btn-primary">Add Photo</button>
```

Now, it looks like you're trying to submit with AJAX, so as long as you're binding to the click event handler of the button, it will work without changing the type, but you should always design your HTML as if JavaScript is not supported. Then, it will submit the form, regardless, and if JavaScript is supported, it'll submit via AJAX instead.

Since it's not submitting *at all*, even though you have JavaScript which should submit on click of the button, then one of two things is wrong with your JavaScript:

1. You're not correctly binding to the click event handler on that element
2. There's some JavaScript error on the page that is preventing your JavaScript from running.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, that was a mistake. However in my case the problem was nested forms preventing the submit to work correctly. I have managed to correct this, so the form is being submitted by itself. However, I find that the javascripts (ajax processing) does not run as such. The code is very much the same from above apart from the button type which equals to submit. Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Im encourting the same issue you where do u have an example that works?

Comment: I need to know how you returning your view in your aciton controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem, frequently, with partial views is not the view itself, but what the partial is embedded in. For instance, if you happen to embed a form within a form, this will cause unpredictable results since that is illegal HTML. Another issue may be the duplication of included scripts, or other problems that we can't really diagnose having only seen the partial.